# How do I save a modified buffer for video resolution uncommented?

Tags: boot, grub2, resolution

I've been getting a "Signal out of range" message when trying to boot up.  Press down arrow, enter to get to recovery menu and go to system root prompt. From there I run

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Then uncomment the

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=1280x1024
```

line and try to save.  It asks for a file name but the prompt is: `/etc/default/grub`.  Can't seem to do anything from there.

Comment: Since you are in root shell, you don't need for `sudo` command. And for the situation – press Enter.

Answer (score 0):

That is normal behavior – Nano asks you about *filename* under which to save file. So just press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and it will save the file.

For exiting Nano, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.

Also, do not forget to mount `/` filesystem in Read-Write mode:

```
mount -o rw,remount /
```